# .net 4.5 Web.Security.Membership.Providers remove throws system.notsupported exception. Why?

Tags: .net, membership-provider

In order to get a better understanding of how to wire in auth functionality in .net MVC4 application, I thought I'd take apart the website that the 'Internet Application' template produces.  Ultimately I'm looking into how I would implement something that is claims aware (such as this: https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.MembershipReboot)

As part of this I've found myself looking at the method WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.PreAppStartInit() which contains the following code:

```
 const string BuiltInMembershipProviderName = "AspNetSqlMembershipProvider";
    var builtInMembership = Membership.Providers[BuiltInMembershipProviderName];
    if (builtInMembership != null)
    {
        var simpleMembership = CreateDefaultSimpleMembershipProvider(BuiltInMembershipProviderName, currentDefault: builtInMembership);
        Membership.Providers.Remove(BuiltInMembershipProviderName);
        Membership.Providers.Add(simpleMembership);
    }
```

If I try to run something similar in a console app it throws a System.NotSupportedException at the point  `Membership.Providers.Remove(BuiltInMembershipProviderName);` is called.  This is to be expected if the collection has had its `SetReadOnly` method called, but it hasn't.  I'm not sure why this is happening in the console app code, but not the Web Application.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This confused me for a while too. The trick is the timing of this initialisation. It needs to be performed at a very early stage. While you are digging around the WebMatrix.WebData namespace, there are a couple of other pieces to look at to see how it all works.

There is an [PreApplicationStartMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.preapplicationstartmethodattribute.aspx) assembly attribute applied:

`[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(PreApplicationStartCode), "Start")]`

The method specified in this attribute will be called as part of the application start-up sequence. The PreApplicationStartCode.Start() method will call WebSecurity.PreAppStartInit() as well as performing some other configuration tasks.

You can replicate this functionality yourself by doing the same thing. Add the PreApplicationStartMethod attribute to your assembly and have it call a 'start-up' method of your own. At this stage, you will be able to play around with the Membership providers collection.